# How to write the read rule for a Firebase Firestore Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following data structure in Firebase Firestore to represent a many to many relationship between clients and users:

```
Clients
  clientId1 {
    users (object): {
      userId1: true
      userId2: true
    }
  }
  clientId2 {
    users (object): {
      userId1: true
    }
  }
```

I query it on Android using the following query:

```
  db.collection("clients").whereEqualTo("users."+uid, true);
```

For userId2, the query should only return clientId1.

If I set the rule to (allow read: if true;)  when I execute the query above I get the correct clients returned.

I would also like to set up a database rule to prevent userId2 from seeing clientId2.

I tried this rule but I get no results returned:

```
match /clients/{clientId} {

  //Allow read if the user exists in the user collection for this client
  allow read: if users[request.auth.uid] == true;

}
```

I also tried:

```
match /clients/{clientId} {

  //Allow read if the user exists in the user collection for this client
  allow read: if resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;

}
```

But neither of the above rules returns any clients.

How do I write the rule?

Comment: so you want exception, different from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question as I was just doing something silly.

My data structure is fine and the correct syntax for my rule is this one:

```
match /clients/{clientId} {

  //Allow read if the user exists in the user collection for this client
  allow read: if resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;

}
```

Given this:

> Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set
>   instead of the actual field values for all of your documents. If a
>   query could potentially return documents that the client does not have
>   permission to read, the entire request fails.

This Android query does correctly implement the right filter for the rule:

```
db.collection("clients").whereEqualTo("users."+uid, true);
```

I am yet to implement my adapter properly.  I wanted to see if I could get the correct data structure / rules / query working first. I was calling it from another listener that was listening on the entire client collection (which fails the rule) and therefore this query was not being called.  Earlier when I set the rule to (allow read: if true;) the initial listener was executing my query and returning the correct results.  This lead me to believe my rule was incorrect, when it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation regarding [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query):

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. To save you time and resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set instead of the actual field values for all of your documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.

So you **cannot** filter the documents that exist in your database using security rules.

Comment: I did read this, but I would still like to understand the best way to secure the data from unauthorised reads?

Comment: To secure data from unauthorised reads you must use `security rules`, to filter data you need to use `queries`.

Comment: So given that, how do I change the structure of the data to secure it? I tried the roles based approach but it still gives me a permission denied. For instance should I be adding a company  as the root collection?

Comment: You should not change the database structure in order to write security rules. Create your database structure and write security rules according to that. So in your case, try to secure your data as explained in the offical doc regarding [Firestore Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query). You should consider using `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access page seems to be the way to do it. As I mentioned I did try this, but I am still get permission denied.  I would prefer to  restructure the data slightly (if I have to) than let a user view a client that is not there's.  I can post an update showing what I tried, if that helps.

Comment: If the new database structure will allow you to query as easy as before and in the same time will also allow you to add the security rules as explained in the offical doc, then go ahead with that. But keep in mind, you don't use security rules to filter data but to allow /disallow users to read/write data. If a query could potentially return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the **entire** request fails. You cannot have partial results.

Comment: Yeah totally agree. You don't design your data structure around security rules. But given the above constraint, it seems to me a tweak maybe necessary to achieve a good structure with secure rules.  I will post an update as my role based approach is not working, and it looks like I am still breaking the filtering rule, Hopefully I can get a working solution.

Comment: Yes, you can give it a try but one more thing to remember, Cloud Firestore Security Rules allow you to control access only to documents and collections in your database. You ca create rules that match anything, from all writes to the entire database to operations on a specific document. But when Cloud Firestore applies your security rules, it evaluates the query against its potential result set, **not against the actual properties of documents** in your database.

Comment: So I finally fixed it, it was something silly.  I didnt use this: allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author; as it will changed it to a one to many relationship.  But thanks very much for your help as I didn't fully understand the relationship between rules and queries.  But now I have a much better understanding.  I will post an answer.